# UICollectionView CompositionalLayout not calling UIScrollDelegate

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

Here is my problem:

**1. ScrollViewDelegate does not get called** once UICollectionView implements compositionalLayout.

With flowLayout and UICollectionViewDataSource the scrollView delegates get called. Once I implement the diffable datasource and CompositionalLayout the scrollView delegates don't get called anymore.

**2. collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast gets ignored** when implementing CompositionalLayout

My understanding is that UICollectionViewDelegate should call UIScrollViewDelegate, I have looked wide and far but no luck. Can someone point me out what am I missing? Am I integrating compositionalLayout wrong?

here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    enum Section {
        case weekdayHeader
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    
    var weekdaysArr = [Weekdays]()
    
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Weekdays>! = nil
    
    private let cellReuseIdentifier = "myCell"
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        self.collectionView.decelerationRate = .normal
        
        configureCollectionView()
        configureDataSource()
        configureWeekdays()
        updateCollectionView()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func configureCollectionView(){
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = generateLayout()
    }
    
    func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .estimated(10),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let weekdayItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        //        weekdayItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 50, bottom: 5, trailing: 50)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.3),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [weekdayItem])
        
        //        let spacing = CGFloat(10)
        //        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = CGFloat(20)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 500)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuousGroupLeadingBoundary
        
        
        
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        
        return layout
        
    }
    
    func configureDataSource() {
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource
            <Section, Weekdays>(collectionView: collectionView)
            { (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, weekday: Weekdays) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
                guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell else {
                    fatalError("Cannot create a new cell") }
                cell.titleLabel.text = weekday.name
                print("weekday.name = \(weekday.name)")
                return cell
        }
        //      let snapshot = snapshotForCurrentState()
        //      dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    
    func configureWeekdays(){
        
        weekdaysArr.append(Weekdays(name: "Monday"))
        weekdaysArr.append(Weekdays(name: "Tuesday"))
        weekdaysArr.append(Weekdays(name: "Wednesday"))
        weekdaysArr.append(Weekdays(name: "Thursday"))
        weekdaysArr.append(Weekdays(name: "Friday"))
        weekdaysArr.append(Weekdays(name: "Saturday"))
        weekdaysArr.append(Weekdays(name: "Sunday"))
        
    }
    
    func updateCollectionView(){
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Weekdays>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.weekdayHeader])
        snapshot.appendItems(weekdaysArr, toSection: .weekdayHeader)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    
    
    
    //MARK: Scroll View Delegate
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("ScrollView decel rate: \(scrollView.decelerationRate)")
    }
    
    public func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("Begin")
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("End")
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        print("END")
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          
          print("Did select a cell here")
          
         }
    
    
}

struct Weekdays: Hashable {
    let identifier: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher){
        return hasher.combine(identifier)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Weekdays, rhs: Weekdays) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

Thank you

Edit: Updated Code -

**Edit: Comparing against Apples sample code from WWDC I found out this behaviour.**

**If I use the sample codes Grid layout**

```
func gridLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2),
                                             heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize,
                                                         subitems: [item])

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
```

When having only 7 Items the Scroll Delegate methods never get called.

I can still scroll though and the expected behavior should be that the scroll delegate methods do get called as I have vertical bounce.

When having about 40 items though and the content is obviously beyond the screen size the scroll delegate does get called.

**Now interestingly when loading my own layout:**

```
func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .estimated(10),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let weekdayItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        //        weekdayItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 50, bottom: 5, trailing: 50)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.3),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [weekdayItem])
        
        //        let spacing = CGFloat(10)
        //        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = CGFloat(20)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 500)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuousGroupLeadingBoundary
        
        
        
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        
        return layout
        
    }
```

The Scroll delegates never get called. Even with 40+ Items.

Any ideas as to how to force UICollectionView to communicate with its ScrollViewDelegates?

Comment: If you don't give the class delegate access to UIScrollView, what's the point of having UIScrollView delegate methods?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How would I go about giving the class delegate access to UiScrollView? Doesn't UICollectionViewDelegate include UIScrollViewDelegate?

Comment: Search for topics that discuss UIScrollView.

Comment: Why does it work though when I remove compositional layout? Not sure if my problem is not described clear enough or not but I don't think searching for topics discussing UIScrollView will solve this. 

I suspect it is the implementation of CompositionalLayout.

Comment: Where do you set `self.collectionView.delegate`?

Comment: I can change class declaration to 
`class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {`
It won't make a difference because UICollectionViewDelegate already includes ScrollViewDelegate

Comment: @LouFranco In this case I have set the delegates through Storyboard. Once that did not work, I have also set the delegate in viewDidLoad() where it calls `configureCollectionView()`

Comment: In the code you are showing, I see no call to set the delegate. Please recheck that you have done this correctly

Comment: Are you getting any warnings when you build or anything in the console when you run?

Comment: No warnings, console is all clear except for a fews print() lines

Comment: Try removing @objc from scrollview functions

Comment: I assume none of your print lines are the scroll ones, right?

Comment: @LouFranco unfortunately your assumption is spot on! I did remove the `@objc`. No difference... I also implemented the delegate method didSelectItemAt and this is working just fine

Comment: I have to ask -- what are you doing to scroll exactly?

Comment: I am out of ideas.  Here is what I suggest -- go get the Apple Compositional Layout example project and just add scroll delegate functions to their delegate.  If that doesn't work, open a Radar.

Comment: @LouFranco unfortunately though I have already added scrollView Delegates to other example codes and there it works. So seems to be just me...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**The answer is using the** `visibleItemsInvalidationHandler` **closure on the section** (`NSCollectionLayoutSection`).

This handler receives updates whenever an event results in an animation. It operates similar to `scrollViewDidScroll` and on horizontal scrolling groups it will be passed all the items, the scroll view offset and the NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection/3199096-visibleitemsinvalidationhandler

Example:

```
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] visibleItems, point, environment in
    self?.currentIndex = visibleItems.last?.indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: fantastic, can't wait to try it out. You just restored my excitement for compositional layouts. Thanks

Comment: Where does this piece of code go?

Comment: doesn't work properly - the behaviour differs depending on scroll direction

Comment: It works but, when I print the value of currentIndex, the same value gets printed multiple times and also the value of currentIndex doesn't go above 10 (I have 11 cells in my collectionView and even even I scroll on the 11th cell, 10 gets printed in the console. 
I'm using this value to change the highlighted cell in the tableView. Due to multiple returns of the same value, it is causing a sort of distortion in the tableview cell getting selected. Ultimately, the correct cell stays highlighted but when I scroll the collectionView, slight distortion happens on tableview cells selection.

Answer (score 12):

**Appears to be an unexpected behaviour of horizontal scrolling groups within UICollectionView compositional layout**

In case someone else encounters the same issue. It seems to be an issue with horizontal scrolling compositional layout groups.

only vertical scrolling groups will trigger the UIScrollViewDelegates.

Unfortunately, it also means that it seems decelerationrate.fast cannot be applied to a horizontal scroll. It will just be ignored.

**Steps to reproduce the issue and analysis**

This behavior can be recreated by implementing UIScrollViewDelegate methods in the wwdc example code "Advancements in Collection View Layout" here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/215/
In the class: OrthogonalScrollBehaviorViewController.swift we find horizontal and vertical scrolling groups.

**Conclusion**

UIScrollViewDelegate only interacts with vertical scrolling groups.
Horizontal scrolling groups do not communicate with the collection view's scroll delegate.

If there is a need for scroll delegate methods in horizontal scrolling groups than a traditional approach with nested CollectionViews and FlowLayout / Custom layout is still needed.

**Remarks**

If someone can point out to me that I am missing something I'd be very grateful until then this will stand as the answer to my above-stated issue.

Thanks to all who have commented.

Answer (score 10):

code snippet:

```
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] visibleItems, point, environment in
    self?.pager.currentPage = visibleItems.last!.indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: again - it doesn't work properly because sometimes it is last page, sometimes first

Answer (score 7):

I have found one convenient way to handle this issue, you can avoid setting orthogonal scrolling and use configuration instead this way:

```
let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider:sectionProvider,configuration: config)
```

This will call all scroll delegates for `collectionview`. Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

UICollectionViewDelegate will call the **scrollDidView** if you vertically scroll the collectionView. In my situation ,I trying to track from horizontal scroll, I'm using this following code to make things work.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: yourCollectionView.contentOffset, size: photoCollectionView.bounds.size)
      let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
      let visibleIndexPath = yourCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) // Current display cell in collectionView
}
```

**It's not the answer for this question**, but hope this help person who searching for tracking current display cell from horizontal scroll in collectionView compositional layout

Answer (score 1):

I tried using

```
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] visibleItems, point, environment in }
```

but the method is getting invoked multiple times on scroll. So the best solution that worked for me was to use timestamp and check the difference in timestamp and only if it is greater than some value say 1 or 2 then only invoke the action.

```
private var currentTimeStamp: TimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 // private parameter to avoid multiple call on scroll, defined outside

section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] visibleItems, location, layoutEnvironment in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        let newTimeStamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        let delta = newTimeStamp - self.currentTimeStamp
        if delta > 2 { 
            performAction()
        }
        self.currentTimeStamp = newTimeStamp
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your use-case, you could also use collection view delegate methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

In these delegate methods - you can react when a specific section is about to display a cell to end displaying a cell