# How to know when horizontal scrolling has stopped in a group within Compositional Layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Does anyone know how to determine when horizontal scrolling has stopped within a compositional layout group?

I'm using UICollectionView with compositional layout and multiple groups.  One group has horizontal scrolling.  From most sources I've found, UIScrollViewDelegate methods can be used, but that only seems to work for vertical scrolling.

Comment: You may want to look at this discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674538/uicollectionview-compositionallayout-not-calling-uiscrolldelegate

Answer (score -3):

A `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. You should be able to set yourself up as the collection view's delegate and (not `UICollectionViewDelegate`, mind, but `delegate`.) You can then receive callbacks like `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`.