# How to get the horizontal scroll percentage using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

#### Question

How can I get the full scrollable content width of a horizontal collection view section using Compositional Layout?

#### Details

I am implementing a `UICollectionView` with Compositional Layout so I can get the nice and easy `section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging` behavior. However, I also need to know the percentage that the user has scrolled through the section so I can keep a custom PageControl in sync. With other collection views that use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` this was a straightforward calculation:

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollProgress = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.contentSize.width
    pageControl.currentPercentage = scrollProgress
```

I've already [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850283/292708) that I need to use `visibleItemsInvalidationHandler` instead of this delegate method. My problem is that with Compositional Layout, the value of both `layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.width` and `collectionView.contentSize.width` is no longer the full width of the *scrollable* content, it's now equal to the frame of the collectionView itself. The value of `scrollOffset` **is** in terms of the full scrollable content size, though.

```swift
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] visibleItems, scrollOffset, layoutEnvironment in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    let contentWidth = layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.width // not the full content width
    //let contentWidth = self.collectionView.contentSize.width // neither is this!
    let scrollProgress = scrollPosition / contentWidth
    self.pageControl.currentPercentage = scrollProgress
}
```

I've tried digging around in `layoutEnvironment` and found nothing equal to the full scrollable content size. I've also tried computing it based on the number of cells but I haven't been able to get it right because of needing to account for contentOffsets and inter-group spacing.

My full layout code and screenshots of the resulting UI is below, in case it helps. Maybe there's a way to change this layout to achieve the same result and get the right value in `contentSize`.

```swift
let layout: UICollectionViewLayout = {
    let itemWidth = itemSize.width - 2 * Const.margin
    let itemLayoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemLayoutSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(itemWidth), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: Const.margin, bottom: 0, trailing: Const.margin)
    section.interGroupSpacing = Const.interItemSpacing
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging
    section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { /* ... */ }

    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}()
```

Starting position:

[image: starting position]

Scrolled to next item:

[image: scrolled to next item]

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else: it's not the solution I was hoping for but I eventually figured out how to compute the content width based on the number of cells. For my layout, the only thing I had to consider was the group width (same as the item width) and the inter-group spacing:

```swift
func contentWidth(forCellCount cellCount: Int) -> CGFloat {
    (itemWidth + Const.interItemSpacing) * CGFloat(cellCount)
}
```

Note that I don't have access to the `cellCount` inside the `visibleItemsInvalidationHandler` so I had to (weakly) capture `self` in that closure and call a method to be able to get that value:

```swift
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] _, scrollOffset, _ in
    self?.handleHorizontalScroll(scrollOffset: scrollOffset)
}
```